# 2007 nissan pathfinder

Tags: cooling-system, overheating, cooling

-I've went down the list,basically a process of elimination,ive changed water pump,thermosatat,flushed system, changed hoses,camshaft senser,flushed heater core,changed heater core sending unit,and it still overheats,Then i found a crack in the top of the radiator

Comment: Hi, can you add more info to your question? For example, which engine do you have? Welcome to the site btw :)

Answer (score 0):

Modern radiators develop cracks after 10 to 15 years and need to be replaced. If your coolant is rusty you have a leak in the motor. Whenever people have cooling system problems take it to the shop for a cooling system pressure check.

Comment: Plastic tops and bottoms crack is a few years.